# Server clock for Blazor web server app with SignalR not working

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, signalr

I want to make a server clock for a Blazor server application, I tried using SignalR but it doesn't work, here is my code:

1. First I made a class called ClockHub

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

namespace BeeTest.Hubs
{
    public class ClockHub : Hub
    {
        public Task SendMessage()
        {
            return Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

2. Then I set it up in program.cs, i added

```
builder.Services.AddSignalR();
builder.Services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
{
    options.MimeTypes = ResponseCompressionDefaults.MimeTypes.Concat(new[] {"application/octet-stream"});
});

...

app.MapHub<ClockHub>("/clockhub");
```

3. Then in my razor page

```
using...

<h4>Server Time: @serverTime</h4>
<MudButton Variant="Variant.Filled" StartIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Save" Size="Size.Large" OnClick="Send" Style="@($"background-color:{Colors.Blue.Default};color:{Colors.Grey.Lighten5};border-radius: 2px;")">Get Server Time</MudButton>

@code{
    private HubConnection? hubConnection;
    private string? serverTime;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl(navigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("/clockhub"))
            .WithAutomaticReconnect()
            .Build();

        hubConnection.On<string>("ReceiveMessage", (time) =>
        {
            serverTime = time;
            js.InvokeVoidAsync("console.log", time);
        });

        await hubConnection.StartAsync();
    }

    private async Task Send()
    {
        if (hubConnection != null)
        {
            await hubConnection.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage");
        
            await js.InvokeVoidAsync("console.log", "ASD");
        }
    }

    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        if (hubConnection != null)
        {
            await hubConnection.DisposeAsync();
        }
    }

}
```

I tried console logging the button click and it registered the click, anyone know how to solve this? I have been stuck for hours

Comment: Why are you adding a second signalR connection for this? You can just render the time directly from the razor...

Comment: I'm sorry, i don't understand what you're talking about, can you please explain it more? thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your code already runs on the server, so just rendering `DateTime.Now` directly on the page will be "Server Time"

Comment: You are calling receivemessage from the client, the hub method is sendmessage.

Comment: hubConnection.SendAsync("SendMessage");

Comment: Thanks everyone, i can't thank you all enough :)